# In a tuple-based check, how do I refer to the tuple I'm currently checking in a subquery?

Tags: sql, tuples, check-constraints

This is the schema I'm currently working with:

```
Studio(name, address, presC#)
```

I'm writing a tuple based check in which no two studios can have the same address. I'd like to write something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Studio ADD CONSTRAINT NoSameAddress 
    CHECK(address NOT IN (SELECT address
                          FROM Studio
                          WHERE 'the outer tuple name attribute' <> Studio.name));
```

How can I refer to the name attribute belonging to the tuple being checked at the current moment?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What is the PK of the table?

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm using Oracle 11g, and the PK is 'name'.

Comment: Why wouldn't a unique constraint on address work for you?

Comment: @LordPeter Because I apparently like to make my life difficult. My textbook labels this problem as "difficult," and I thought of a solution which would make it more difficult. I completely forgot about unique constraints!

Answer (score 0):

Use a unique constraint on `address`:

```
ALTER TABLE Studio ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ_ADDR UNIQUE(address)
```